# Multiplicación de matrices sin dimensiones compartibles

Tags: python, matriz

Estoy multiplicando una matriz de 3x1 por una de 3x1 en python, esto no se puede hacer ya que el numero de renglones de la primera matriz debe coincidir con el numero de columnas de la segunda, por o tanto no se puede hacer, sin embargo, cuando o hago, me arroja una matriz de 3x1 como resultado, ¿De donde sale este resultado?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Es necesario que vayas a [edit] e indiques cómo estás haciendo la multiplicación, para que puedan responderte qué pasa.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y [edit] tu pregunta con el código que estás utilizando y datos de ejemplo para que alguien pueda figurarse lo que pasa y responder. Un saludo.

Comment: Sin ver el código, sería puro adivinar.

Answer (score 2):

Si estas usando `numpy` al aplicar un producto entre dos `np.array()` usando el operador `*`, estas ejecutando la función `np.multiply()`. Esta función hace referencia a un producto llamado **Hadamard product** el cual se explica en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Hadamard product]

Por esta razón al multiplicar dos arrays de 3x1 da como resultado un array de 3x1

```
import numpy as np
a = array([[1],[2],[3]])
b = array([[4],[5],[6]])
print(a*b)
#Resultado array([[4],[10],[18]])
```

Si deseas hacer un producto matricial debes usar la función
`a.dot(b)` the numpy

```
a = array([[1],[2],[3]])
b = array([[4,5,6]])
print(a.dot(b))
#Resultado array([[ 4,  5,  6],
#                 [ 8, 10, 12],
#                 [12, 15, 18]])
```

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-multiply-in-python/